# Special symbols cannot be stored in SQL Server from ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a website in [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) 3.5 that takes some input in text format and saves it in a SQL Server 2005 database.

The database field is `varcahar(50)`.

But I can't do it if data in text box contains special symbols like <,>,#,@,.

It generates a client script error showing security error.

For scripting I am using JavaScript.

Comment: The database doesn't care what the symbols are. The problem is going to be in your script or your code-behind. Can you post some code?

Comment: u r right the prob is with the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John Nolan writes, this most likely is the result of ASP.NET's built in request validation.

You have to turn off the built in validation and roll your own:

You can turn off the validation at page level:

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

or at application level (in web.config):

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages validateRequest="false" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Don't forget to encode all output from your application, expecially after turning off the request validation.

Check out [this article](http://www.asp.net/(S(ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg))/learn/whitepapers/request-validation/) on the subject.

In order to protect your application you have to follow common Web application security guidelines and among others encode all your output that was generated directly or indirectly by users to avoid Cross Site Scripting (XSS). Microsoft has provided an [Anti XSS library](http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS) to simplify this. OWASP has an XSS prevention [cheat sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: wont this be a threat to my applications security

Comment: Well, even if you don't turn off the request validation you should validate your input and encode your output. The built in request valdation only provide a basic partial protection.

I've updated my answer with some additional links to AntiXss resources as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it doesn't like the <> characters. Try turning off validaterequest in your page directive. WARNING: This will allow malicious content through though. It is probably best to encode your input.